# How to add data on Back4App database without migrate with parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, database-migration, back4app

How to add data on Back4App database without migrate with parse database.
Can I create database on back4app and implement using code without migrating. we can't find client key and applicationid using back4app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do this. Use the dashboard (sign in back4app -> click in your app parse dashboard) or connect through API. In order to find your keys: sign in Back4app -> click in your app features -> core settings.